# The Canonical navigation bar has diverged from the canon

Tags: bug, design, top-bar

Possibly due to the recent CSS refactoring, the pseudo-Canonical navigation bar no longer matches the top bar of ubuntu.com sites. Here is how they compare in my Chrome (Windows):

#### AU bar

[image: current]

#### Canonical bar

[image: canonical]

Possible cause: although both sites declare Ubuntu as the font for the top bar, only ubuntu.com loads it as a web-font.